# Poincaré-Bendixson theorem in $\mathbb{R}^{1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, poincare-duality

The theorem of Poincaré-Bendixson states that:
For an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and a continuously differentiable vector field $F:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and a compact set $K \subset U$, where F has no equilibrium in K, $p \in K$ and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow K$ is the solution of the initial value problem with an initial value of $f(0)=p$ and if $f$ doesn't reach the boundary of K, then there exists an periodic orbit $z$ so that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $t>0$ with $||f(t)-z||<\epsilon$.

Now I have to formulate and prove the version of the theorem for n=1 (so in $\mathbb{R}$).

I really have no idea how to start on this problem. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: There are no limit cycles in $\Bbb R^1$, how should that work? One can define trapping regions. For time-dependent DE periodic equations may have (non-trivial) periodic solutions. What exactly do you expect to obtain?

Comment: Your statement of P-B theorem is incorrect. In particular, it is incorrect for your purposes. Here is the correct statement: Let $U\subset \mathbb R^2$ be positive invariant and contains only finite number of equilibria. Then for any $x_0\in U$ its $\omega$-limit set can be: 1) an equilibrium, 2) a closed curve, 3) a set of points such that for any $y$ from this set $\omega(y)$ is an equilibrium. That is, P-B theorem classifies the limit sets on the plane. You are asked to do the same (classify the limit sets) on the real line.